# Power BI Dynamic date value

Tags: powerbi, dax

Hi I need to know if there is any simpler alternative for picking up a value of a particular month from a table for a 'IF' statement in Power BI.

For instance, in the below table I want to use a 'IF' statement which compares the prev to prev months purchase to its current months purchase example:- I want to check if Jun-20 purchase is higher then Apr-2020 purchase, so when I have Jul-20 data it compares with May-20.

[image]

I have written a formula but its too complex and want a simpler dynamic one.

```
lst_mnth = CALCULATE(SUM('POS Data'[POS])-CALCULATE(SUM('POS Data'[POS]),DATEADD('POS Data'[Month],-1,MONTH)))

prev_2mnths=(CALCULATE(SUM('POS Data'[POS])-CALCULATE(SUM('POS Data'[POS]),DATEADD('POS Data'[Month],-2,MONTH)))-'Measure'[lst_mnth]

check=IF('Measure'[lst_mnth]>Measure'[lst_mnth]',"Higher","Lesser")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ParallelPeriod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/parallelperiod-function-dax) to look back or forward. In your example you mention that for the month Jul, you want to compare May data.

[image: Example Parallel Period]

Note: you will need a date column, from you image you have 'Jan-20' if that is a text field then this will not work, if it is just a date that is formatted to show only 'Jan-20' then it should work. For all time intelligence functions like ParallelPeriod, YTD etc is is recommended that you have a calendar table.

```
Two Months Ago = CALCULATE ( SUM ( YourTable[Pos] ), PARALLELPERIOD ( YourTable[Month], -2, MONTH )
```

It is a bit neater than the 'dateadd' in your measure, and you'll still need to do some sort of IF clause to compare.

```
Compare = 
VAR CurrentMonth = SUM(YourTable[Pos])
VAR TwoMonthsAgo = CALCULATE(SUM(YourTable[Pos]),PARALLELPERIOD(YourTable[Month], -2, MONTH))
RETURN
IF(CurrentMonth > TwoMonthsAgo, 'Higher', 'Lower')
```

Comment: Hi ,Thank you for the response however I am not looking for a sum value here  I am looking for individual value for that month and not and aggregated value June the value is 210445 against April 24652.

Comment: Your formulas in your example are calculated columns? My example image that shows June the value is 210445 against April 24652 is a measure not a column, if you want it dynamic, it is best to use a measure. You can move the sum to a sumx for a row by row iterator style comparable to a calculated column